# Can I connect 220V AC supply to Node MCU (or any arduino)pin D1 and D3 while node MCDU is power off?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

Can I connect 220V AC supply to node MCU pin D1 and D3 while node MCDU is power off?

Comment: Are you trying to kill yourself? 220V can be fatal. Go and talk to a qualified electrician before you do anything more.

Comment: Short answer: **HELL** no. You should not connect AC supply lines to any low voltage pins, under any circumstances. The insulation on the wires is not sufficient for that voltage, and it would **pose a serious risk of fatal injury**. Oh by the way, it would fry your Arduino, but that is not important compared to killing anybody who touched anything connected to the Arudino.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, never! 220V is way way way too much for a microcontroller. The Uno runs on 5V, the ESP8266 on 3.3V. You should never connect any more voltage than that to the microcontroller. Also you must not connect a negative voltage to the microcontroller pins.

Besides the voltage difference: You should also not connect a voltage to the pins of a microcontroller, while the microcontroller itself is turned off (meaning that it does not have the necessary supply voltage). In that case a parasite current would run through the clamping diodes, which powers the microncontroller, until the diodes get blown.

---

As an **important** side note: **Don't do anything with mains power (like 220V AC), until you really know, what you are doing!!! One error and it can kill you !!!**